# tmux create panes programmatically

Tags: tmux

I want to create tmux panes programmatically. e.g. I have a list of commands to execute, and I'll create a shell script that will invoke a tmux command along with the commands to execute in each pane, dynamically. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

[tmuxify](https://github.com/tonchis/tmuxify) (lib I wrote) does this. You can take a look at the code where the `tmux send-keys` command is used [here](https://github.com/tonchis/tmuxify/blob/master/bin/tmuxify#L40) to have an idea on how to get started.

Keep in mind that you need to create the split where you want to execute the command first. Use `tmux split-window` for this.

I also recommend reading `man` sections for both commands above. It's very well explained. If you have any doubts, comment below.

Comment: number of panes I'll open is not fixed. I'll have to generate the commandline dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

[Tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) also does this well. It's a ruby gem that uses a yml file that stores your layouts and can programatically set them up for you.

It's github page has a decent readme, but it's basically like so:

### Set up:

```
mux new [project]
vim the/autogenerated/project.yml # Edit the config to suit
```

### Open your project:

```
mux [project]
```

### An example config:

```
windows:
  - editor:
      layout: tiled
      panes:
        - cd ~/code/source/dir && git status
        - cd ~/code/source/dir && vagrant up && vagrant ssh -- -t 'sudo su; /bin/bash' # log in as sudo, the final /bin/bash keeps the shell open
        - cd ~/code/source/dir && vagrant up && vagrant ssh -- -t 'sudo su some_user && cd ~/mounted/dir/ && vim ./; /bin/bash' # log in, go to your mounted code and vim
        - # do nothing
  - logs: tail -f log/development.log
```

As a side note: It can also run commands when opening panes, so you can ssh into some machines, log in as various users etc etc.

Tmuxify may also cover the same ground, so the good thing is you have options. The bad thing is... you have to choose ;)